# Grouping data based on a xml through xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I was looking to group data in a xml through XSLT 1.0, could someone please suggest a way to do it.

```
<product>
  <group>
    <groupName>Maruthi</groupName>
    <groupOrderNumber>1</groupOrderNumber>
        <metaData>
          <metaDataName>sequenceOrderNumber</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>1</metaDataValue>             
       </metaData>
       <metaData>
          <metaDataName>HeaderName</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>Maruthi 800</metaDataValue>           
       </metaData>
  </group>
  <group>
    <groupName>Maruthi</groupName>
    <groupOrderNumber>1</groupOrderNumber>
        <metaData>
          <metaDataName>sequenceOrderNumber</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>2</metaDataValue>             
       </metaData>
       <metaData>
          <metaDataName>HeaderName</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>Maruthi Alto</metaDataValue>           
       </metaData>
  </group>
  <group>
    <groupName>Honda</groupName>
    <groupOrderNumber>2</groupOrderNumber>
        <metaData>
          <metaDataName>sequenceOrderNumber</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>1</metaDataValue>             
       </metaData>
       <metaData>
          <metaDataName>HeaderName</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>Honda City</metaDataValue>           
       </metaData>
  </group>
  <group>
    <groupName>Honda</groupName>
    <groupOrderNumber>2</groupOrderNumber>
        <metaData>
          <metaDataName>sequenceOrderNumber</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>2</metaDataValue>             
       </metaData>
       <metaData>
          <metaDataName>HeaderName</metaDataName>
          <metaDataValue>Honda Amaze</metaDataValue>           
       </metaData>
  </group>
</product>
```

I want to display content as below, Manufacturer order is based on the group order number and Model Orders are based on the sequenceOrderNumber.

```
Manufacturer: Maruthi
        Model: Maruthi800
        Model: Maruthi Alto
 Manufacturer: Honda
        Model: Honda City
        Model: Honda Amaze
```

Please find the stylesheet, which is able to group the data, please suggest how can i order based on the sequence order number.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:nms="http://www.example.org/consolidated"
 exclude-result-prefixes="nms"> 
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-    declaration="yes" />
<xsl:key name="groups" match="//nms:group" use="nms:groupName"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="//nms:group[count(. | key('groups',nms:groupName)[1]) = 1]">
 <xsl:sort select="nms:groupOrderNumber"/>     
 <table border="1">
 <tr> <xsl:value-of select="nms:groupName"/> </tr> 
 <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',nms:groupName)">                
      <xsl:for-each select="./nms:metaData">        
         <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="nms:metaDataName"/> </td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="nms:metaDataValue"/> </td>
         </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each> 
 </table>      
 </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you want your output to be just the specific text you have in your question, or do you want it in some other format, like HTML or another XML schema?

Comment: Also, I can't see how `sequenceOrderNumber` plays any part in this, so I've ignored that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks matt,  sequenceOrderNumber  is important for me as i have usecase to display in a order considering sequenceOrderNumber .

Comment: in your example, all `sequenceOrderNumber` elements have a `metaDataValue` sibling value of `0` so I can't see how they're meant to be ordered, but I hope my answer gives you enough to get something working.

Comment: @RajeshLalam  Do a search: *grouping* is probably *the* most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Michel, we are using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Then start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I am able to group the data with muencian approach, but the only pending thing was order the data based on sequenceOrderNumber and one more constarint was sequenceOrderNumber  might be there or might not be there, if sequenceOrderNumber   is there data need to be ordered based on sequenceOrderNumber .

Comment: "*I am able to group the data with muencian approach*" Then edit your question and show the stylesheet you have.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original question where you didn't specify the XSLT version, I've written this, which is a solution in **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//group" group-by="groupOrderNumber">
            Manufacturer: <xsl:value-of select="groupName"/><xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//group[groupOrderNumber=current-grouping-key()]">
                Model:<xsl:value-of select="metaData[metaDataName='HeaderName']/metaDataValue"/> <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses the [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) instruction to group on the `groupOrderNumber` value in the `group` branch.

I then used the `current-grouping-key` in the `select` of the inner `xsl:for-each` to just iterate over the groups matching the current grouping key.

The output is:

```
        Manufacturer: Maruthi
            Model:Maruthi 800
            Model:Maruthi Alto
        Manufacturer: Honda
            Model:Honda City
            Model:Honda Amaze
```

You might want to add formatting of your own, but since I'm not aware of any specific formatting requirements the above XSLT should at least get you the basics of what you're looking for.

Incidentally, I'm using `<xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>` as the carriage return in the output.

Although this is not for the version you are using, I'll leave this answer up in case anyone looking for a grouping solution in XSLT 2.0 finds this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is still confusing, because (a) your stylesheet uses a prefix but the shown input has no namespaces and (b) your stylesheet produces an output that's different from the one shown.

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="groups" match="group" use="groupName"/>

<xsl:template match="/product">
    <xsl:for-each select="group[count(. | key('groups', groupName)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="groupOrderNumber"/>     
        <table border="1" width="250px">
            <tr>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="groupName"/></td>
            </tr> 
            <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', groupName)">  
                <xsl:sort select="metaData[metaDataName='sequenceOrderNumber']/metaDataValue"/>   
                <tr>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="metaData[metaDataName='HeaderName']/metaDataValue"/></td>
                </tr> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>      
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```