# Group data when condition is met

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm working on a XSL solution to convert a XML file to CSV. The end product need me to read set of invoices from the XML and then group them according to the invoice number and then list the items below the invoice number.

I'm not a fluent in XSL but I wrote the entire thing but I'm stuck on creating the tables. Below is the out put I'm required to create.

[image: Preffered output]

I tried to find away to make it work but only way I came close with [this posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613986/grouping-data-based-on-a-xml-through-xsl) second answer. Following that I came up with the below code. Also like to mention I'm using XSL v 2.0

```
<!-- Line items -->

<!-- Full path for the elemnts I'm just lazy to tye the same thing again and again -->
<xsl:variable name="fullPath" select="/BatchObject/BaseTypeContainerList/BaseTypeContainer/BaseTypeObject/Metadata"/>

<!-- Full path for line items. I'm just too lazy -->
<xsl:variable name="fullPathLine" select="/BatchObject/BaseTypeContainerList/BaseTypeContainer/BaseTypeObject/Metadata/LineItemRows/LineItemRow"/>

<xsl:for-each-group select="$fullPath" group-by="$fullPath/Fields/Field[@Label = 'Invoice Number']/Value" >

<xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>

<xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="$fullPath/Fields/Field[@Label = 'Invoice Number']/Value = current-grouping-key()">
            <xsl:value-of select="('&#xD;',$fullPathLine/Fields/Field[@Label = 'Line']/Value,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="($fullPathLine/Fields/Field[@Label = 'Description']/Value,';')"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
    
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

But the out put is looks like this,

```
01108840

 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 ;Ekstra lang HÃ¸y skillevegg, ekstra Gummimatte, ekstra Pallet 1200x800 Hylle 1458x216x54 Hylle 1296x216x54 ForhÃ¸yningsramme med Bakdeksel 486x270 Bakdeksel 648x378 Pallet 1200x800 Pallet frame 1200X800 Skuff 486x486x216 Hylle 486x486x54 Hyllestige med kortere VerktÃ¸yplate 486x270 Bakdeksel 486x270 Gummimatte, hylle ;

01108849

 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 ;Ekstra lang HÃ¸y skillevegg, ekstra Gummimatte, ekstra Pallet 1200x800 Hylle 1458x216x54 Hylle 1296x216x54 ForhÃ¸yningsramme med Bakdeksel 486x270 Bakdeksel 648x378 Pallet 1200x800 Pallet frame 1200X800 Skuff 486x486x216 Hylle 486x486x54 Hyllestige med kortere VerktÃ¸yplate 486x270 Bakdeksel 486x270 Gummimatte, hylle ;
```

But out put I want to create is

```
01108840
    
1;Ekstra lang HÃ¸y

2;skillevegg,

3;ekstra Gummimatte,

4;ekstra Pallet 1200x800
```

XML data sheet.

```
<BaseTypeContainerList>
<BaseTypeContainer ID="2292be4cbac2405097d8b40fdbe0068b" DBID="0" Archived="0001-01-01T00:00:00" Destroy="0001-01-01T00:00:00" Created="2020-03-31T12:12:00.2302687+02:00" Modified="2020-03-31T12:12:00.2302687+02:00" CreatedOrder="0" Status="Complete" RejectionMailSendt="false">
  <BaseTypeObject xsi:type="Email" ID="5885e93bfc8e404187bc274417ee4ac5">
    <Metadata>
      <Fields>
        <Field ID="186e155a1fb6442b872a88dc5f6e8a7f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Master">
          <Value>KGH_Modulsystem</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="4911c6aa66864547b5e81ae92e1241af" MappedFieldID="04672b33e6f14285abc11a866c2a993e" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Agreement Number">
          <Value>130</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="6941c04028f149b4b48cd3eb659bb71d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Seller">
          <Value>112885</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="90236e52a3194885b4812e4d84afda76" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Buyer">
          <Value>Modul-System AS</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="c03844760c5342caab89253570eb6af9" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Customer Number">
          <Value>9095</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="510fe5c44e1d4e9d8499a83cfae92802" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Invoice Number">
          <Value>01108840</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="d34638d12dd64e519bbb5da0b92d1f0b" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Date" Status="Complete" Label="Invoice Date">
          <Value>28.11.2019</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="c121fadca3d34278a68aa2feb26fc969" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Invoice Type">
          <Value>CI</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="2d489e9bb66b49559ee634e140df33b0" MappedFieldID="d9f08184ff57469cb9bb37fa28014249" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Delivery Term">
          <Value>DDP</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="ee9cd176f29245b0978de6d0706dc478" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Delivery Term Location">
          <Value>Skjetten</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="6c23fea43499495590efebb0b4cea541" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Packages">
          <Value>1</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="66fdcc37d3ae4eafa21523a7ec1937d9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Package Type">
          <Value>PX</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="e6d8303294a8400e933ee622196dbcc3" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallet Weight">
          <Value>23</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="a4548889d35d44159c1f19d55017412f" MappedFieldID="04672b33e6f14285abc11a866c2a993e" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Batch Gross Weight">
          <Value>3000</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="05ce757f80a14c1182c59f070be06522" MappedFieldID="04672b33e6f14285abc11a866c2a993e" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Batch Net Weight">
          <Value>2500</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="fce2f65786314fc2ae466639b8c4a7f9" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Over-Head Cost">
          <Value>45,22</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="160f608391854226a6e3fc3d363a5490" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Total Amount">
          <Value>452,23</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="0cd4d1027d9d44b490e306f0e04e36e6" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Currency">
          <Value>EUR</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line" />
        <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity" />
        <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description" />
        <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
          <Value>94032009</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number" />
        <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
          <Value>N</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
        <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
        <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin" />
        <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount" />
        <Field ID="bc54c6e2147949899ed875c189753846" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Table Amount">
          <Value>452,23</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="e182f943a4694123b7f7182b2b017fca" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Country Sender Receiver">
          <Value>SE;NO</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="e3136a0631c346149a3cfd48e7824f85" MappedFieldID="ce76fa9ee7c74b1aa4367e2eac8de23b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Email">
          <Value>stian.svarholt@kghcustoms.com</Value>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <LineItemRows>
        <LineItemRow ID="0" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>1,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Ekstra lang</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>406,74</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
        <LineItemRow ID="1" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>2</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>2,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Høy skillevegg, ekstra</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>24,90</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
        <LineItemRow ID="2" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>3</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>3,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Gummimatte, ekstra</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>13,38</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
      </LineItemRows>
      <BaseTypeContainer ID="1320da9c026b4b6ead49f7a736676570" DBID="0" Archived="0001-01-01T00:00:00" Destroy="0001-01-01T00:00:00" Created="2020-03-31T12:12:01.9314102+02:00" Modified="2020-03-31T12:12:01.9314102+02:00" CreatedOrder="1" Status="Complete" RejectionMailSendt="false">
  <BaseTypeObject xsi:type="Email" ID="b77a7d029687426cb9e60d017df5bb58">
    <Metadata>
      <Fields>
        <Field ID="186e155a1fb6442b872a88dc5f6e8a7f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Master">
          <Value>KGH_Modulsystem</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="4911c6aa66864547b5e81ae92e1241af" MappedFieldID="04672b33e6f14285abc11a866c2a993e" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Agreement Number">
          <Value>130</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="6941c04028f149b4b48cd3eb659bb71d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Seller">
          <Value>112885</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="90236e52a3194885b4812e4d84afda76" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Buyer">
          <Value>Modul-System AS</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="c03844760c5342caab89253570eb6af9" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Customer Number">
          <Value>9095</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="510fe5c44e1d4e9d8499a83cfae92802" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Invoice Number">
          <Value>01108849</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="d34638d12dd64e519bbb5da0b92d1f0b" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Date" Status="Complete" Label="Invoice Date">
          <Value>28.11.2019</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="c121fadca3d34278a68aa2feb26fc969" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Invoice Type">
          <Value>CI</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="2d489e9bb66b49559ee634e140df33b0" MappedFieldID="d9f08184ff57469cb9bb37fa28014249" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Delivery Term">
          <Value>DDP</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="ee9cd176f29245b0978de6d0706dc478" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Delivery Term Location">
          <Value>Skjetten</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="6c23fea43499495590efebb0b4cea541" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Packages">
          <Value>3</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="66fdcc37d3ae4eafa21523a7ec1937d9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Package Type">
          <Value>PX</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="e6d8303294a8400e933ee622196dbcc3" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallet Weight">
          <Value>23</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="a4548889d35d44159c1f19d55017412f" MappedFieldID="04672b33e6f14285abc11a866c2a993e" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Batch Gross Weight">
          <Value>3000</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="05ce757f80a14c1182c59f070be06522" MappedFieldID="04672b33e6f14285abc11a866c2a993e" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Batch Net Weight">
          <Value>2500</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="fce2f65786314fc2ae466639b8c4a7f9" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Over-Head Cost">
          <Value>19,27</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="160f608391854226a6e3fc3d363a5490" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Total Amount">
          <Value>192,72</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="0cd4d1027d9d44b490e306f0e04e36e6" MappedFieldID="e05d5ee159484e81b071b8bd85cca134" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Currency">
          <Value>EUR</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line" />
        <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity" />
        <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description" />
        <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
          <Value>94032009</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number" />
        <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
          <Value>N</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
        <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
        <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin" />
        <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount" />
        <Field ID="bc54c6e2147949899ed875c189753846" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Table Amount">
          <Value>192,72</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="e182f943a4694123b7f7182b2b017fca" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Country Sender Receiver">
          <Value>SE;NO</Value>
        </Field>
        <Field ID="e3136a0631c346149a3cfd48e7824f85" MappedFieldID="ce76fa9ee7c74b1aa4367e2eac8de23b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Email">
          <Value>stian.svarholt@kghcustoms.com</Value>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <LineItemRows>
        <LineItemRow ID="0" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>1,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Hylle 1458x216x54</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>33,92</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
        <LineItemRow ID="1" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>2</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>1,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Hylle 1296x216x54</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>33,44</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
        <LineItemRow ID="2" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>3</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>1,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Forhøyningsramme med</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>19,20</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
        <LineItemRow ID="3" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>4</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>2,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Bakdeksel 486x270</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>31,82</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
        <LineItemRow ID="4" FromPage="1">
          <Fields>
            <Field ID="26fc88ba67cf4f8fb8e5a25383e9403f" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Line">
              <Value>5</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="86381702799b4265a48d7d96eba3abbf" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Quantity">
              <Value>3,00</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="2d42106344c54189a9045ee0dedb51b6" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Description">
              <Value>Bakdeksel 648x378</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="55d85303fa4c4c37bc51ac0562d887f1" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="HS Code">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="6caaa2a60bc842c193ac8590550108b0" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Article Number">
              <Value>94032009</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="a16255ad1e9549b48a9a31d001629b36" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Pallets">
              <Value>N</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="64cd6620ab5a456997694c8592b9e87b" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Colli" />
            <Field ID="c43102102ce64a1db469408a5b131f4d" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Net Weight" />
            <Field ID="0565320a98c84652963ce0732cac7ad9" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Origin">
              <Value>SE</Value>
            </Field>
            <Field ID="252a9390778540edac6520d3f9f260b8" Type="Text" Status="Complete" Label="Amount">
              <Value>53,07</Value>
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </LineItemRow>
      </LineItemRows>
```

I know the data set is big but wanted show you what I've to work with. So hope some can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
 <xsl:for-each select="$fullPath/Fields/Field[@Label = 'Invoice Number']/Value = current-grouping-key()">
```

you want

```
 <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
```